# Number of nodes in a subtree at given depth, given depth of all nodes in main tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a tree with depth of each node known. Is there an optimal way of finding number of nodes in a subtree rooted at node (N1) at depth d (with respect to N1).

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know the exact data structure you have but what you can do is this :

1. Get the depth of the root under investigation, suppose it is N.
2. Check all the nodes with depth N + 1 for its parent link. If the parent link is the root then increment the counter.